# How to use the Resize function with the offset function in VBA code for a User Defined Function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, resize, user-defined-functions, offset

I have 10 years worth of monthly returns of an asset. I am trying to create a function that can give me the annualised returns of this series of monthly return data. I would like to use the Offset function to go to the last monthly returns date, select an array of periods that I choose (3 months back, 6 months back, 12 months back, 24 months back etc) so that I can get the annualised return of a series of returns from the end date back to a specific period.

The goal is to calculate the monthly average monthly returns of the last 3 months, 6 months, 12 months etc.

However, the parameters for the Offset function in VBA are different to those in normal Excel functions. I think I need to use the .Resize function to resize my Offset function.

Here is how the function works in Excel

```
=GEOMEAN(1+OFFSET($W$4,MATCH(LARGE($V$4:$V$10485,1),$V$4:$V$10485,0)-1,0,-$AJ17,1))-1
```

Rewritten so that you can understand my variables

```
=GEOMEAN(1+OFFSET(ref,MATCH(LARGE(Dates,1),Dates,0)-1,0,-period,1))-1
```

Here is the code that I have written so far...

```
Function Returns(ref As Range, Dates As Range, Period As Integer) As Variant

    With Application.WorksheetFunction

        Returns = .Geomean(1 + ref.Resize(-Period, 1).Offset(.Match(.Large(Dates, 1), Dates, 0) - 1, 0))-1



    End With



End Function
```

Please, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out a few of my errors.

A) I declared the variables incorrectly.

B) I used a negative number for resize as I wanted the function to go to the end of the series and count back (to get 6 month. 12 month, 24 month returns). This does not work.

As an alternative, I have used LARGE to find the nth largest date and select the array below that point.

See code below.

Function AnnReturns(Ref As Variant, Dates As Variant, Period As Variant, M As Variant) As Variant

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction


    AnnReturns = .FVSchedule(1, (Ref.Offset(.Match(.Large(Dates, Period), Dates, 0) - 1, 0).Resize(Period, 1))) ^ (1 / M) - 1


End With
```

End Function